# How to create an on and off toggle button for google maps react for a heatmap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-2, react-google-maps, google-maps-react

I want create a button that  turns on and off the heatmap part of this map. I have trouble doing this in react javacript. Not sure where to put the logic and where to put the button ? any help , this an example of the code that google provides [Google HeatMap Toggle buttons][1] . 
I want to integrate this with this code

```
export class MapContainer extends Component{

    state = {
        showingInfoWindow: false,  //Hides or the shows the infoWindow
        activeMarker: {},          //Shows the active marker upon click
        selectedPlace: {},
        isHeatVisible : true ,  
        isMarkerVisible: true       //Shows the infoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
    };
    handleToggle1 = () => {
        this.setState({isMarkerVisible: !this.state.isMarkerVisible})
      }
    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({isHeatVisible: !this.state.isHeatVisible});
      }
    onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
        this.setState({
            selectedPlace: props,
            activeMarker: marker,
            showingInfoWindow: true
        });

    onClose = props => {
        if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
            this.setState({
                showingInfoWindow: false,
                activeMarker: null
            });
        }
    };
          render() { 

            const gradient = [
                "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)",
                "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)",
                "rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)",
                "rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)",
                "rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"
              ];

         let heat =     <HeatMap
              gradient={gradient}
              opacity={3}
              positions={this.props.policeCall.map(({M,N}) => {
                  return { lat: M, lng: N};
              })}
              radius={30}
              />
        let marker = {this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O }) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                name={A}
                info={B}
                priority={L}
                position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
                story={O}
              />
            );
          })}


        return (
            <div>
        <div className="floating-panel">
          <button onClick = {this.handleToggle}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
        <div className="map-container">

            <Map
                google={this.props.google}
                zoom={14}
                style={mapStyles}
                scrollwheel={true}
                initialCenter={{
                    lat: 32.71573699,
                    lng: -117.16108799



                }}
            >


        {this.state.isMarkerVisible? marker:null}
        {this.state.isHeatVisible ? heat: null}



                <InfoWindow
                    marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                    visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
                    onClose={this.onClose}
                >

                <React.Fragment> 
            <h4 style={h4style}>ID: {this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
            <h4 style={h4style}>Date: {this.state.selectedPlace.info}</h4>

            {/* <h4 style={h4style}>
              Priority: {this.state.selectedPlace.priority}
            </h4> */}
            <h4 style={h4style}>
              Crime Level: {this.state.selectedPlace.story}
            </h4>
          </React.Fragment>


                </InfoWindow>
</Map>
</div>
</div>

        );
    }
}


const Mcontainer = GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: '',
    libraries: ["visualization"]
})(MapContainer);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    policeCall: state.policeCall.policeCall
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Mcontainer);
```

I want to create a separate toggle just for markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state variable called `isHeatmapVisible: false`

Then inside the `<Map>` tag

```
<div id="floating-panel">
  <Button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</Button>
</div>
```

The `toggleHeatMap()` will be:

```
function toggleHeatmap() {
    this.setState({isHeatmapVisible: !this.state.isHeatmapVisible})
}
```

And finally instead of directly showing the Heatmap assign it to a variable:

```
let map = <HeatMap
    gradient={gradient}
    opacity={3}
    positions={this.props.policeCall.map(({M,N}) => {
        return { lat: M, lng: N};
    })}
    radius={30}
    />
```

In the render():

```
{this.state.isHeatmapVisible ? map : null}
```

Comment: Sure, can you add a demo to the existing code in Codepen and I'll add the heatmap toggle on it

Comment: not sure how to set it up a react project on codepen

Comment: let me try , can you just use the code from the question , or what other code do you need ? i can post it on here

Comment: i actually just edit the file where the heatmap uses the positions via variable positions here is a similar demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pnhf6p also from a similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107150/react-google-maps-not-displaying-heatmap-lat-and-long-not-working-for-my-posit]

Comment: ?? was not able to make the code pen ? where you , thanks

Comment: app: https://react-kwnqgq.stackblitz.io

code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kwnqgq

Comment: no it did not , its actually stoping my heatmap from showing up

Comment: Does the stackblitz app above look fine?

Comment: yes it works but when i add markers it removes markers as well, how can you do it where you have toggle for heatmap and one for markers

Comment: ill add my code in the question that i currently have on  codepen

Comment: the one you shared is the same file as above. can you share the one with markers. Or create a new question.

Comment: i put my code im using for the markers  on the question in stackoverflow i just edit , the code is for  Map.js https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kwnqgq?file=Map.js

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it worked for you. It'll be easier for other to find.

Comment: just one question can i do this , i posted the code in my question im trying to do the same with markers i did with with heatmap , declare a variable let markers = ... , its on my question if you can give me some advise thank you so much

Comment: No, when you map items you need to have an id. That;s a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react

Comment: how would we set it up with the keys inside markers function ?

Comment: can you share codepen of what you have tried so far in a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152553/a-toggle-button-on-and-off-for-markers-in-google-maps-react

Comment: thank you i did the same strategy with the markers except im not able to declare it.