# A toggle button on and off for markers in google maps react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, google-maps-react

I want to create button that removes all markers for the google maps react, i already have it working for the heatmap but it does not let me do the same strategy for the markers ? is it because the mapping that is being done ? than you i already set up all the other functions and states just one last step

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, InfoWindow, Marker, HeatMap } from 'google-maps-react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const mapStyles = {
    width: '45%',
    height: '54%'
};
const h4style = {
    color: "black"
  };


export class MapContainer extends Component{

    state = {
        showingInfoWindow: false,  //Hides or the shows the infoWindow
        activeMarker: {},          //Shows the active marker upon click
        selectedPlace: {},
        isHeatVisible : true ,  
        isMarkerVisible: true       //Shows the infoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
    };
    handleToggle1 = () => {
        this.setState({isMarkerVisible: !this.state.isMarkerVisible})
      }
    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({isHeatVisible: !this.state.isHeatVisible});
      }
    onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
        this.setState({
            selectedPlace: props,
            activeMarker: marker,
            showingInfoWindow: true
        });

    onClose = props => {
        if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
            this.setState({
                showingInfoWindow: false,
                activeMarker: null
            });
        }
    };
          render() { 

            const gradient = [
                "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)",
                "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)",
                "rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)",
                "rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)",
                "rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)",
                "rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"
              ];

         let heat =     <HeatMap
              gradient={gradient}
              opacity={3}
              positions={this.props.policeCall.map(({M,N}) => {
                  return { lat: M, lng: N};
              })}
              radius={30}
              />





        return (
            <div>
        <div className="floating-panel">
          <button onClick = {this.handleToggle}>HeatMap</button>
          <button onClick = {this.handleToggle1}>Markers</button>
        </div>
        <div className="map-container">

            <Map
                google={this.props.google}
                zoom={14}
                style={mapStyles}
                scrollwheel={true}
                initialCenter={{
                    lat: 32.71573699,
                    lng: -117.16108799



                }}
            >



                {this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O }) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
              name={A}
              info={B}
              priority={L}
              position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
              story={O}
            />
          );
        })}

        {this.state.isHeatVisible ? heat: null}



                <InfoWindow
                    marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                    visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
                    onClose={this.onClose}
                >

                <React.Fragment> 
            <h4 style={h4style}>ID: {this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
            <h4 style={h4style}>Date: {this.state.selectedPlace.info}</h4>

            {/* <h4 style={h4style}>
              Priority: {this.state.selectedPlace.priority}
            </h4> */}

            <h4 style={h4style}>
              Crime Level: {this.state.selectedPlace.story}
            </h4>
          </React.Fragment>


                </InfoWindow>
</Map>
</div>
</div>

        );
    }
}


const Mcontainer = GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: '',
    libraries: ["visualization"]
})(MapContainer);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    policeCall: state.policeCall.policeCall
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Mcontainer);
```[my map application][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfSJV.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have `handleToggle1` function setting the **isMarkerVisible** flag then on `render()` you can have this:

```
render() { 
    const markers = this.state.isMarkerVisible ? this.props.policeCall : []
    ... <your code>
    return <div> 
    ... <your code>
       {markers.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O }) => {
          return (
            <Marker
                onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                name={A}
                info={B}
                priority={L}
                position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
               story={O}
            />
          );
        })}
    ... <your code>
    </div>
}
```

All the ellipsis is your code but for brevity I only added where you will need to make changes to toggle markers.

Comment: so where does the        {markers.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O }) => (<Marker .../>))}
go ?

Comment: Instead of your `{
this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O })) => {
return <Marker ...> 
})}`

Comment: I notice that my heat map needs work because the way its currently set up is assuming the data comes back right away but in the case when the data does not return right away the heat map is not going to display anything because its being set to a variable before the data gets back to the front end

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O }) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={A}
          info={B}
          priority={L}
          position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
          story={O}
        />
      );
    })}
```

to

```
{this.state.isMarkerVisible ? this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, B, M, N, L,O }) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          name={A}
          info={B}
          priority={L}
          position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
          story={O}
        />
      );
    }) : null}
```

Comment: No need to do it, it'll show markers only if the isToggleVisible == true

Comment: Just making the change as I put in the post should be enough

Comment: I notice that my heat map needs work because the way its currently set up is assuming the data comes back right away but in the case when the data does not return right away the heat map is not going to display anything because its being set to a variable before the data gets back to the front end